# How can I download all the pdf files linked in a webpage in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, download-manager

I would like to download all the files of a given type (such as pdf) linked from [a web page](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193x/lectures/).

I used to use DownThemAll in Firefox, but the addon is ["Not compatible with Firefox Quantum"](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/downthemall/).

I have tried https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/download-star/, but I don't find out how I can use the addon to specify to download all pdf files linked in the webpage.
Do I miss something?

What addons or other tools can do the task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be an extension? I would think wget would be more suited to the task.

### wget (on Bash):

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --accept pdf --no-directories https://www.example.com/pagewithpdfs.htm
```

(courtesty of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23775416/4463400)

This downloads all of the PDFs directly linked on `https://www.example.com/pagewithpdfs.htm` and puts them in the current folder.

wget is installed by default on most Linux distros.

## wget (on Windows):

If you're using Microsoft Windows 10, you can still use wget by getting the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) ([wsl.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop)) from the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6).

```
wsl.exe wget --recursive --level=1 --accept pdf --no-directories https://www.example.com/pagewithpdfs.htm
```

Comment: For windows you can also install cygwin and add the bin directory of cygwin to your path.

Comment: As an alternative, you can get it for Windows without WSL and without Cygwin: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm It still works even in modern Windows versions, but of course it does not support as many features as recent versions, and it hasn't got security updates since about 13 years, so I would use it only with trustworthy sites. However, it might be a quick-and-dirty solution in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use [downthemall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/), it allows you to filter a page by any file extension and download all files at once.

Comment: Thanks. My post mentioned the addon is "Not compatible with Firefox Quantum". https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/

Comment: That was true for a while, but it is fixed now.